Персональные данные VPN, mail.ru
Когда включен VPN, и открыт сайт mail.ru,
сообщение следующего содержания:

Мы ценим вашу приватность! Мы и наши партнеры используем такие
технологии, как файлы cookie, и обрабатываем персональные данные,
такие как IP-адрес или информацию браузера, для персонализации
рекламы, которую вы видите. Это помогает нам показывать вам более
релевантную рекламу и улучшает вашу работу в интернете. Мы также
используем эти данные для измерения результатов или настройки
содержания нашего веб-сайта. Поскольку мы ценим вашу
конфиденциальность, мы просим вашего разрешения на использование этих
технологий. Вы всегда можете изменить или отозвать свое согласие позже
в разделе "Политика конфиденциальности".
Хранение и (или) доступ к информации на устройстве Использование ограниченных данных для выбора рекламы Создание профилей для
персонализированной рекламы Использование профилей для выбора
персонализированной рекламы
Создание профилей для персонализации контента Использование профилей для выбора персонализированного контента Определение
эффективности рекламы Определение эффективности контента
Понимание аудитории с помощью статистики или комбинации данных из разных источников Разработка и совершенствование сервисов
Использование точных данных геолокации
Активное сканирование характеристик устройства для идентификации

Черным цветом выделила текст. Хотелось бы от вас узнать ответы. Что подразумеваться под этим?

Все что угодно, что mail.ru захочет :-)

@Kromster напишите ответ, если знаете, хотя бы примерно. спасибо
